# Cellediting textarea should overlap it's grid

Tags: extjs

I have a problem with a cellediting grid having a textfield with an editor specified as textareafield.

```
editor: {
  xtype: 'textareafield',
  height: 300,
  enableKeyEvents: true,
  selectOnFocus: true,
  flex: 1,
  listeners: {
    specialkey: function (field, e) {
      specialKeyFunction(field, e);
    },
    afterrender: function (field, e) {
      field.bodyEl.setWidth(200);
    }
  }
}
```

See:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/27ee&view/editor

Now due to the absolute positioned textarea within the relative positioned parents you can barely see the textarea.

I want the textarea editor to behave like a datepicker or like a combobox boundlist. Means the editor should be added to the body but still be attached to the cell it belongs to..

Comment: Means you want editor to be shifted just below the respective cell ?

Comment: I want the editor to be completely visible overlapping the whole table.. But since there are many position relative/overflow hidden parents I kinda have to make the editor render to the body and still place it at the position of the cell element when editing

Comment: I didnt understand properly.Can you give some illustration

Comment: The textarea has a height of 300px. But if you click in the company name you cant see it's full height because the grid is overflow hidden. You have to scroll which is awful. I want to have the textarea of the editor fully visible as an overlay of the grid. If you click on the datepicker it's overlaying the grid as intended. Same behaviour I'd like to have to the textareafield.